# Relation about Gateaux differentiable and differentiable

Tags: convex-analysis

Assume there is a multivariable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. I want to know the relation between Gateaux differentiable and differentiable. That is, if $f$ is differentiable, is it Gateaux differentiable? If $f$ is Gateaux differentiable, is it differentiable? Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the definitions of both Gateaux differentiable and differentiable (since they are always precisely the same).

Comment: differentiable is what we meet in undergraduate calculus course (see, e.g., Def. 9.11 in P212 of baby Rudin). Gateaux differentiable (at x) is defined as follows: (1)the directional derivative $f'(x;v)$ exists for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, (2)there exists (unique) $f_G'(x)\in\mathbb{R}^*$ such that $f'(x;v)=<f_G'(x),v>$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, where $\mathbb{R}^*$ means the dual space of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $f$ is differentiable at a  point $a$ if   there is a vector $v$ such that 
   $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{|f(x)-f(a)-\langle v,x-a\rangle |}{|x-a|}=0 \tag1$$
   This is also called Fréchet differentiability, to distinguish it from other kinds.
2. $f$ is  Gâteaux  differentiable at a  point $a$  for any nonzero vector $u$ the limit
   $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ f(a+hu)-f(a) }{h}   \tag2$$
   exists. This is also called the directional derivative.
3. $f$ is  Gâteaux  differentiable at a  point $a$ with *linear differential* if there is a vector $v$ such that for any nonzero vector $u$ we have
   $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ f(a+hu)-f(a) }{h}=\langle v,u\rangle  \tag2$$
   The vector $v$ is called the Gâteaux differential of $f$. Normally, the words *Gâteaux differential* are used only in this case, when we have linearity.

It is true that (1) implies (3). The easiest way to prove this is to rewrite (1) as $f(x)=f(a)+\langle v,x-a\rangle +r(x)$ where the *remainder* $r(x)$ satisfies $r(x)/|x-a|\to 0$ as $x\to a$. Then plug into (2).

It is obvious  that (3) implies (2).

In spaces of dimension $n\ge 2$, (2) does not imply (3), and (3) does not imply (1). Examples are given in [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Relation_to_the_G.C3.A2teaux_derivative).